# sys.sleep in apply and parSapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I use a code that interrupts the execution of a command for a given time in order to not reach the (crunchbase) API-Limit.

```
    managed_call <- function(f, events = 44L, every = 60L) {
    force(f)
    minute_ <- rep(NA, events)
    function(...) {       
    m_dif <- as.numeric(Sys.time() - minute_, units = "secs")
    minute_[!is.na(m_dif) & m_dif > every] <<- NA
    calls_remaining <- sum(is.na(minute_))
    if (!calls_remaining) {
    message("Close to API limit, pausing for ", 
    round(every - max(m_dif), 3), " seconds")
    Sys.sleep(every - max(m_dif))
    minute_[which.max(m_dif)] <- NA
    minute_[Position(is.na, minute_)] <<- Sys.time()
    f(...)
    } else {
    minute_[Position(is.na, minute_)] <<- Sys.time()
    f(...)
      }
     }
    }
```

When applying a normal apply or lapply command, this peace of code gives me the following warning:

```
      Updated <- function(x){is.null(crunchbase_GET(x))}
  
      > abc <- unlist(lapply(websites,Updated))
      Close to API limit, pausing for 1.25 seconds
      Close to API limit, pausing for 1.119 seconds
      ...
```

However, I tried another option with makeCluster and parSapply:

```
library("parallel")

abc<- logical(100) 

Updated <- function(x){is.null(crunchbase_GET(x))}
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "PSOCK")
clusterExport(cl, varlist = "websites")
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, library(rcrunchbase))

abc <- parSapply(cl = cl, X = websites, FUN = Updated, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

The warning message does not appear now. Thus, I was wondering if the actual  Sys.sleep() command is even executed, and, if not, if there is any possibility to make my code run with parSapply.

I am really sorry that I cannot give a good sample that can be reproduced for this specific case, as a user_key is required to use rCrunchbase and thus to retrieve information on the API Limit etc.

Answer (score 1):

`message` does not "escape" `parSapply`, it is lost, same for `cat` and `warning`. The ability to pass basic information from a `cl` child to the parent process is difficult.

An alternative (extension actually, since they rely on `parallel`) is [`future`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) and [`future.apply`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply/index.html), as they do deal with console output.

```r
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)
parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:3, function(i) { message("Hello: ", i+100); Sys.getpid(); })
# [[1]]
# [1] 22680
# [[2]]
# [1] 14504
# [[3]]
# [1] 27084
```

But `future`:

```r
library(future)        # plan, cluster
library(future.apply)  # future_lapply
# using the same 'cl'
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
future_lapply(1:3, function(i) { message("Hello: ", i+100); Sys.getpid(); })
# Hello: 101
# Hello: 102
# Hello: 103
# [[1]]
# [1] 22680
# [[2]]
# [1] 14504
# [[3]]
# [1] 27084
```

(Variations can demonstrate that `cat` and `warning` also escape the child processes.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this solution also compatible with sys.Sleep()?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't, have you tried it and see problems?

Comment: I tried it and first of all, I really have to say thank you, because I really like the approach. However, the results I get applying the standard lapply code and the future_lapply are quite different, resulting in unavailability of much more websites using future_lapply. Also,  while the lapply code stopps many times while processing the first 1000 URLs in my list, the future_lapply command seems to not stop once. I noticed now that the error should lie in some of the steps previous to sys.sleep(). Could you imagine what could cause trouble there?

Comment: The function used: `Updated <- function(x){is.null(crunchbase_GET(x))}` , the future approach:
`cl <- makeCluster(detectCores(), type = "PSOCK")
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
def <- unlist(future_lapply(websites, Updated))
stopCluster(cl)`, the lapply approach (gives correct results I think):
`abc <- unlist(lapply(websites,Updated))`

Comment: One last additional comment: I get various warnings about a HTTP 429 Error, indicating that I indeed passed the API limit

Comment: Without heavy testing, I would suspect that `m_dif` can be `NA`, rendering many of your calculations as warnings if not errors. For instance, start with `minute_=NA`. That makes `m_dif` NA as well, and therefore `minute_[!is.na(m_dif) & m_dif > 60]` is empty (length 0). This makes `calls_remaining` always the original length, since all of `minute_` are still NA. On top of that, `as.numeric(..., units="secs")` isn't a thing that I know of, so `m_dif` is not `POSIXt`, so `round(every - max(m_dif),3)` might be a problem, too. Have you gone step-by-step through this to test each value?